# Question on the IRS Form 1098-T

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, education, school

Is this a new form? I was doing TurboTax and I filled out the information and it wouldn't let me submit my tax refund because it said the IRS is still working on the forms.

I did read something that the school has till the end of Jan to send you a form and is that what I use to fill out the sections?

Just curious as to how I should proceed.

Comment: It [is not a new form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_1098-T), but is one that the school fills out and sends to you - it is not one that _you_ fill out.

Comment: Do I need to request it?

Comment: In addition, IRS won't actually accept returns before Jan. 29. If you were/are able to complete your return now -- without receiving W2/1099/1098 forms -- EROs like Intuit/Turbotax will usually let you submit earlier, but they'll just hold it until the IRS opens, so you don't get any benefit from doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not new.

[Form 1098-T](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/form-1098-t-tuition-statement) is a form that schools/universities send out to their students to report the amount of tuition paid. It is used to qualify for [tax benefits for education](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/tax-benefits-for-education-information-center).

Like many tax documents that you receive from other companies, you may have to wait until February before you receive it. If you haven’t received it by the middle of February, you can contact the school and ask about it.